# Find row that throws error in R

Tags: r, debugging

I have more than a thousand rows in my dataframe. One of its columns *should* hold a single word. I want to lowercase this column:

```
df$precedingWord <- tolower(df$precedingWord)
```

But surprisingly, I get an error

```
Error in tolower(df$precedingWord) : 
  invalid input '/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-E-L/WR-P-E-L0000106.data.ids.xml:  Ik zeg jij hebt goede ogen í ½í¸³RT @IMoonen Ik tel 16 schepen voor de kust, dat mag je gerust een #' in 'utf8towcs'
```

From this I gather that one a specific row, df$precedingWord doesn't hold a single word, but more than a sentence, namely */home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-E-L/WR-P-E-L0000106.data.ids.xml:  Ik zeg jij hebt goede ogen í ½í¸³RT @IMoonen Ik tel 16 schepen voor de kust, dat mag je gerust een #*.

Now to debug this, I'd like to know the row ID of the sentence that is thrown. How can I find this out?

Comment: wrap the test in a `tryCatch` and report in the error function

Comment: try `df$precedingWord <- enc2utf8(df$precedingWord)` to eliminate the problem entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` to search for the string:

```
x <- c("a",
       '/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-E-L/WR-P-E-L0000106.data.ids.xml:  Ik zeg jij hebt goede ogen í ½í¸³RT @IMoonen Ik tel 16 schepen voor de kust, dat mag je gerust een #')

grep("/home/nobackup/SONAR/COMPACT/WR-P-E-L/WR-P-E-L0000106.data.ids.xml:", 
  x, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] 2
```